# MacOS cannot install flask-mysqldb

Tags: python, flask-mysql

I am trying to install "flask-mysqldb" library but it cannot be installed due to mysqlclient.

```
ld: library not found for -lzlib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
```

I have also put but it did not work.

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/lib/pkgconfig"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"

export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zlib/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I am happy to hear your suggestions.